# Is it necessary to submit sitemap to www and non www?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, no-www

I have submitted my website to Google Webmaster Tools with both `www` and with `no-www`. I had made the domain without `www` to my preffered domain and have submitted a sitemap.

My question is should I also submit a sitemap to the one whit `www`?

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need to submit a sitemap for the version (here with `www`) you don't want to use.

Remember submitting a sitemap to your Google Webmaster Tools account helps indexing of the site. Therefore, you submit a sitemap only for a site you want to see in Google's index.

Answer (score 3):

You should submit the sitemap only to the version of the site that matches the URLs in the sitemap.

- Submit this sitemap *only* to the no-www site in Google Webmaster Tools:

  ```
  <loc>http://example.com/mypage.html</loc>
  ```
- Submit this sitemap  *only* to the www site in Google Webmaster Tools:

  ```
  <loc>http://www.example.com/mypage.html</loc>
  ```

The URLs in your sitemap should match your preferred domain preference.  Google uses which URLs appear in a sitemap as one way of figuring out canonical URLs (see [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)).  Your preference setting in webmaster tools is another way.   In order not to confuse Google, the two should match.

So in your case, I would expect all the URLs in your sitemap to include the `www.` and you to submit the sitemap to the www site in Google Webmaster Tools.